# OOP in java for Android studio app

Tags: java, android, oop

Im new to java, although have about a years experience with python and programming in general. I somewhat understand object oriented programming although since just recently teaching myself java, I dont understand how/why a piece of code works.
The code is for an android app created in android studio, where I am trying to learn how to create an app using the google maps API. The java code is this:

```
package com.example.harry.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

As I understand it, this code creates the class, but I cant see where an object of the class is produced in order for the code to be run.
All of my programming experience has come from python/procedural programming.

In addition to not fully understanding how this code works, if i was to call the method .getUiSettings(), what object would I call this on?

Comment: Stackoverflow might not be the best place to ask questions like these. They're pretty vague and looks like you're looking for a mentor of sorts. There are better places where you can find one

Comment: Majority of programs made for android written as listeners - they are created by outside facility, usually invisible from the point of regular developer, and then these objects are notified when something happens in "outside world", by calling exposed methods on them. There is a whole mountain of things under this question, probably not suitable for this site, as already has been said.

Comment: Maybe read this --> [The Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you have is your class definition -- i.e. a set of properties and methods that belong to your object, in this case `MapsActivity`. When you go onto an Android device and open your app, the Android operating system reads your app's `AndroidManifest.xml` to determine which Activity is your app's main activity. (If you made this in Android Studio, I'm guessing that this activity was automatically designated as the main activity, and you shouldn't have to change anything.) The Android operating system creates an instance of that class, and then calls a [specific sequence of methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) to alert your object that certain things are happening.

`getUiSettings()` is a method of the `GoogleMap` object. In your activity's `onCreate()` method, you call `getMapAsync()`. This launches a background thread to download the map information from Google without blocking up your main thread. When that information has been fully received, `onMapReady()` is called with the prepared `GoogleMap` as the parameter. You then save this object for later use with

```
mMap = googleMap;
```

If you wanted to access the map's UI settings, you'd call the method on your map object

```
mMap.getUiSettings();
```

Android coding is very much based around asynchronicity and callbacks and can be a little confusing at first. I would agree with @Vucko that perhaps you should find an online course or a more experienced programmer to learn from.

Comment: I have tried many online courses but most seem a little too complex for me at the minute, I understand it will take some time but im finding it hard to get started as I dont have anybody I can go to because I have finished my school course.

Comment: That's fair -- it took me a month of reading through websites and tutorials to get a grasp on Android programming. A good knowledge of Java is helpful, so I'd start there. The learning curve for Android is very steep, but relatively small. You'll find it hard to get started, but once you get going, it's usually pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

The map object is created by the map fragment asynchronously and returned to the listener, your activity. 
And `getUiSettings` would be called on the `GoogleMap` object.
As you can see in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) it's a method of the object.

As mentioned in comments, maybe SO isn't the place for this question. I found out recently there is a [code review site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) in the stack exchange network. Maybe it's more appropriate.